# How to restrict value for Input field?

Tags: javascript

I have Input filed - But it Should Accept only following string

A,C,D,K,1,2,3 and 5

If any other value is put it should not accept.

How Can I handle this?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<HTML>
<BODY>
<input id="inputField" value="" onkeypress="validateInput(event)"/>

</BODY>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateInput(e)
{
 debugger;
  let userinput =String.fromCharCode(e.which);

  let regularExpression = new RegExp(/[ACDK1235]/);
  let isGoodInput = regularExpression.test(userinput);
  if(!isGoodInput){
    alert('User typed bad input[ ' +userinput + ' ], so I am blocking input!');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else{
    alert('User typed good input[ '+userinput+' ]');
  }
}
</script>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression .on onChange prop of text input you just validate the data with regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

May be on the keypress event:

```js
//A,C,D,K,1,2,3 and 5
var allowedKeyCodes = [65,67,68,75,49,50,51,53]
function validate(){  
 return allowedKeyCodes.includes(event.keyCode);  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return validate()" >
```